# Does it follow from $\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c)$ that $a \mid b$? If not, under what conditions on $a,b,c$ does this implication hold?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

Let $a, b,$ and $c$ be positive (odd) integers.

I know that the implication
$$a \mid b \implies \gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c)$$
holds.

Here is my:

> **INITIAL QUESTION:** Does the converse
> $$\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c) \implies a \mid b$$
> also hold?  If not, under what conditions does the converse hold?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Consider $a = 1$.  Then for any positive (odd) integer $b$, then
$$1 = \gcd(a, c) \mid \gcd(b, c) \implies 1 = a \mid b,$$
whence the implication holds.

Consider $a = 3$, $b = 5$, and $c = 7$.  (Note that $\gcd(a,b)=1$.)  Then we have
$$1 = \gcd(a, c) \mid \gcd(b, c) = 1 \implies 3 = a \nmid b = 5,$$
whence the implication does not hold.

Here is my:

> **FINAL QUESTION:** As it is easy to cook counterexamples for the implication
> $$\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c) \implies a \mid b$$
> when $\gcd(a,b)=1$, can you think of a counterexample for which $\gcd(a,b)>1$?

Comment: Consider pairwise coprime numbers $a,b,c$, then $2a, 2b, 2c$ is a counterexample with gcd$(a,b)=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @SeverinSchraven!  How is that a counterexample?  Note that I am only considering **odd** integers $a, b, c$ such that $\gcd(a, c) \mid \gcd(b, c)$.

Comment: If $a, b, c$ are pairwise coprime, then surely $\gcd(a,b)=1$, @SeverinSchraven?

Comment: My point was not so much that you multiply by $2$, you can pick anything you like. Clearly you have for $a,b,c$ pairwise coprime and $0<n\in \mathbb{N}$ that gcd$(na,nc)=n =\text{gcd}(nb,nc)$. However, $na$ still does not divide $nb$.

Comment: By the GCD Universal Property in the linked dupe $(a,c)\mid (b,c)\iff (a,c)\mid b,c\iff (a,c)\mid b,\,$ which does not imply $\,a\mid b,\,$ as *very* obvious counterexamples show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many counterexamples with $\gcd(a,b)>1$.

For $(a,b,c)=(PQ,RQ,Q)$ where $P,Q,R$ are positive odd integers satisfying $Q\gt 1$ and $P\not\mid R$, we have
$$\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c),\qquad a \not\mid b\qquad\text{and}\qquad \gcd(a,b)>1$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  Welcome back.  =)

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).